# confuse with swt canvas.redraw

Tags: java, canvas, swt

i'm a new guy in swt, in the code below.when i click test button,the console print "start" "end" and "in canvas",why it not print "start" "in canvas" "end". if it's not a problem ,how can i let the console print "start" "in canvas" "end".Thanks a lot.

canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
            System.out.println("in canvas");
        }
    });
    test.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("start");
            canvas.redraw();
            System.out.println("end");
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master in swt, but generally, if you make some call like redraw(), repaint(), postInvalidate() or other similiar, in almost all gui frameworks, these invocations don't redraw the content directly, they just put an instruction to do that in a gui-drawing queue, so they are often executed some time after your actual call. Thus in your code, you first finish the widgetSelected, and then your "redraw" task is executed on a gui-thread.

Sometimes, like in java, there is a similar method, for instance in swing there is paintImmidiatelly(), but it could be invoked only from a GUI thread, which is generally the case, when you get an GUI event in your listener, then often this is a call from gui thread, that have catched this event.

Maybe you can use update() in swt, to force it to be drawn in place.

The redrawing works as following:

```
redraw() marks the widget an invalidated. On next redraw-system-action this area will be repainted.
update() forces all outstanding redraw() requests to be completed NOW.
```